# CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync does not always work

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a collection if it does not exist.

First, I create my DocumentClient by:

```
public DocumentClient CreateClient(ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = null)
{
   return new DocumentClient(new Uri(this.AccountEndpoint), this.AccountKey, connectionPolicy);
}
```

Now that I have my document client (let's call it `documentDbClient`), I attempt to use `CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync`:

```
var documentDbClient = dbConnection.CreateClient();

await documentDbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("mydatabase"),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = "testcollection" });
```

Now, I would expect this to create a collection named `testcollection` under my database named `mydatabase`. However, nothing happens. No collection is created, no exceptions are thrown.

I thought perhaps it was just slow, and so I waited 30 minutes and went back to the portal to see if my collection had been made...

It hadn't.

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I have discovered that if I change the name of the collection that I am attempting to create, it works. I have previously created and deleted the collection many times and now it appears that Azure is failing to create it 90% of the time.

Comment: Are you creating and deleting the same document over and over, like in a unit test situation? Multiple times per minute or hour?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, that's what I am doing.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Multiple times per hour would be more accurate.

Comment: If random collection  id for test is acceptable, we could use random collection id for test.

Answer (score 2):

So, you're likely running into a throttling situation when repeatedly creating and destroying collections. Here's an excerpt from the Table API section of the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#develop-with-the-table-api-preview) (which applies equally to document collections):

> The rapid rate of creation of tables is detected and throttled. We
>   recommend that you look at the rate of creation of tables and lower it
>   to less than 5 per minute.

The current throttle rate is 5 creates / minute. So, for a unit-testing scenario, you'd need to work around this (e.g. keeping a collection, but just emptying its contents after each test run).

*Note: I notified the product team, that the throttle mention is only in the Table API section, and to update the FAQ accordingly.*

Comment: thank you. However, I was most certainly not trying to create a collection 5 times a minutes. It was more like once every 10 minutes. Perhaps the throttling is more severe for collections? Aditionally, I tried a day later and that collection name I was using no longer works. I can create it via the portal, but not code. Not sure what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a .Wait() to the end of database creation and then the collection creation. This will wait for both tasks to complete.

```
_client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "dbName" }).Wait();

_client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("dbName"), new DocumentCollection { Id = "collectionName" }).Wait();
```