# Azure file share strange behaviour

Tags: azure, azure-files

This question is about Azure **FILE** storage, not BLOB.

I have created a file storage/share in Azure. I then wrote some code to access an FTP account, download the files and put them into my file storage.

I run this code as a WebJob, triggered at specific times.

To test, I've had to run the code a number of times, which has opened a whole can of wtf worms, one of which can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44991300/596841).

Now, when I discover that my WebJob is not behaving as I expect, I delete the job and all the files it has downloaded (I use Azure Storage Explorer to do this).

However, when I refresh (either the portal or storage explorer), I see that files are still going into the File Storage. I thought, "Oh, perhaps it is taking some time to delete the WebJob from MS servers...". It's been more than 20 minutes now. Surely the WebJob, which does not display in the portal anymore (because I deleted it 20 minutes ago), is no longer running?

Why am I continuing to have files added to my file share, despite deleting the WebJob responsible for downloading them? I can see the files in both the portal and storage explorer. I cannot delete them from the portal as it tells me there has been an error and to try again later. No error code, no help, nothing.

> Failed to delete directory 'testshare/2017070800'. Error: There was an error processing your request. Try again in a few moments.

Even restarting my web app, which I really should not have to do, has no effect.

Comment: Can you FTP to WebJob directory and see if binaries were deleted.
site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\{job name}

Comment: @NareshPodishetty The Job does not exist (I just checked via FTP).